# Detecting file corruption with batch script

Tags: delphi, batch-file, filesize

How can I uses commands to check that the size of new file is significantly smaller than the one it's replacing?

I have a batch file running every night which, amongst other things, calls an application `UpdVMem.exe` which creates a cut down members database `VMembers.Adt` from the main file `Members.Adt`. This file is then moved to remotes sites with the same script.

On a few sites, at periodic intervals the VMembers.Adt will be corrupted. I have no idea why, as we've ruled out the table being locked for editing (by my Delphi Membership software). It will be often deceptively appear the same size but contains less than half the records.

Even better would be a set of commands which could detect this corruption or a failure in the execution of `UpdVMem.exe`, as the size alone is not the best indicator.

Thanks

Comment: Which kind of copy are you using? There are specialized programs like the Unix `rsync` that might work better than a plain copy.

Comment: It just uses the standard ( copy 'source' 'destination' ) but the VMembers file is corrupted when it's produced so that's not where the problem lies.

Comment: If you want to detect something, you need a rule. What's your rule? File size < N?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [ERRORLEVEL](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/errorlevel.php) command to check the exit code of `UpdVMem.exe` in batch file. If the UpdVMem.exe is developed by you then you can use the [Halt](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/XE2/en/System.Halt) procedure to send "meaningful error codes" to the batch file (ie when you catch some exception when creating the VMembers.Adt file).

Comment: Thanks, this is an ideal solution as UpdVMem.exe is developed by myself so i can put in one or more Halts where it may be failing. However since I can't currently find the latest source, are there any alternatives to ERRORLEVEL? as the current errorlevel is always 0

Comment: I'm not sure what sort of alternative youre looking for... if you mean some other way (than detecting the UpdVMem.exe failing) to detect is the VMembers.Adt file corrupted then I can't think of any as you wrote "It will be often deceptively appear the same size but contains less than half the records" which rules out checking for file size. So only way seems to be to write an special program which validates the file before you overwrite the old one.

Comment: You're right unless I find that source code and write in a retry, I'd have to write a validation program which uses recordCount or exception and makes a retry. This one's abit too advanced for MS commands maybe :p